# Video not playing in ios4?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing an video from url using MPMoviePlayerViewController class and it is working fine in all version of 3.(3.0,3.1,3.1.2,3.1.3)but in iOS4 video is not playing ? Have any one track this issue ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling 3 to 4 hrs. i Found out the solution of the issue. Here is the solution:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoUrl];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpViewController];

[mpViewController.view setCenter:yourView.center];
[mpViewController release];
```

Cheers !!!!